# Is it correct to identify the cause of a vagary?

Tags: word-usage

If I write, for instance, "Variation in sleep quality is responsible for the vagaries of students' academic performance," is this a correct use of the word *vagaries*, which is defined as an *inexplicable* change?

Comment: Probably a better word choice could have been made.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Logic would say not, I think.
'Fluctuations of performance' would be more suitable in your sentence.